# Labelling a bar chart with multiple data sets

Tags: plotting, labeling

I'd like to plot a bar chart with two data sets $\{a_1,a_2,\dots,a_n\}$ and $\{b_1,b_2,\dots,b_n\}$ in such a way that the columns appear in the order $\{a_1,b_1,a_2,b_2,\dots,a_n,b_n\}$ **and** that each pair of columns is labelled with labels $\{\ell_1,\ell_2,\dots,\ell_n\}$.

Here's a fairly minimal working non-example:

```
BarChart[Transpose[{{1, 2, 3, 4}, {1, 1, 3, 5}}], ChartLabels -> {"A", "B", "C", "D"}]
```

which plots this

[image: wrongly labelled bar chart]

whereas I would like the labels to be A B C D and, if possible, centred under each pair of columns.

Many thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
BarChart[Transpose[{{1, 2, 3, 4}, {1, 1, 3, 5}}], ChartLabels -> {{"A", "B", "C", "D"}, None}]
```

which produces this:

[image]

See the `ChartLabels` section of `BarChart` for similar tricks.

Comment: Is there a way to do this with just two datasets, wherein there's no particular pairing between the elements as above? _I.e._, I'd like to have something like two side-by-side datasets, `{1,2,3,4}` and `{5,6,7,8}`, with the labels `"Dataset 1"` and `"Dataset 2"` underneath each one.